# Matlab quiver arrow length

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am working on the following code:

```
function myquiver

clc
R=2.3;
C=1.2;
V=@(t) 3*sqw(t,1,10);
F=@(t,VC) (V(t)-VC)/(R*C);
[T,VC]=meshgrid(linspace(0,25,10),linspace(0,0.5,10));
S=(3*sqw(T,1,10)-VC)/(R*C);
L=sqrt(1+S.^2);
quiver(T,VC,1./L,S./L,'r','ShowArrowhead','off','AutoScale','off')
axis([0,25,0,0.5])
shg

function y=sqw(t,T,d)
r=mod(t,T);
y=(r<d*T/100);
```

This produces the following image:

[image]

Now, what I want to do is make each of the quiver arrows the same length based on the axes. I don't want to change axis([0,25,0.05]). That is exactly what I want. But how can I scale each quiver arrow so that they are all the same length in this particular image?

I am hoping to see an idea that I can use should I do another plot with say axis([0,10,-30,50]).

I'm hoping to see a full code example and an image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider two coordinate systems. First, the *world coordinate system*, which the data are in. For example `1./L` and `S./L` are world coordinate representations. Second, the *plot coordinate system* which we define such that one unit of distance is the width and height of the plot window. I.e. a horizontal vector with unit length in plot coordinates would exactly span the entire plot width, and similarly a vertical vector with unit length in plot coordinates would exactly span the entire plot height.

What you appear to be asking is how to scale each vector so that they are all some fixed length in plot coordinates. It's not difficult to see that for some vector defined in world coordinates `(x_world, y_world)` the following functions transform the world coordinate to plot coordinates.

```
x_plot = x_world / x_span
y_plot = y_world / y_span
```

Where `x_span` and `y_span` are the width and height of the plot in world coordinates (in your case `25` and `0.5` respectively).

We would like to know what scaling factor to apply to `x_world` and `y_world` so that `(x_plot, y_plot)` is some fixed length. Observe that we **must apply the same scaling factor in x and y to retain the original direction**. Mathematically this can be described by the equation

```
d = sqrt((s*x_world / x_span)^2 + (s*y_plot / y_span)^2)
```

where `d` is the desired length in plot coordinates and `s` is the scale factor we need to determine.

Solving the equation for `s` we get

```
s = d/sqrt((x_world / x_span)^2 + (y_plot / y_span)^2)
```

which gives us a solution.

```
function myquiver
    xmin = 0; xmax = 25;
    ymin = 0; ymax = 0.5;

    R=2.3;
    C=1.2;
    V=@(t) 3*sqw(t,1,10);
    F=@(t,VC) (V(t)-VC)/(R*C);
    [T,VC]=meshgrid(linspace(xmin,xmax,10),linspace(ymin,ymax,10));
    S=(3*sqw(T,1,10)-VC)/(R*C);
    L=sqrt(1+S.^2);

    x_span = xmax - xmin;
    y_span = ymax - ymin;
    % Compute the scale factor so that vectors are 10% of plot window
    d = 0.1;
    X_world = 1./L;
    Y_world = S./L;
    s = d ./ sqrt((X_world / x_span).^2 + (Y_world / y_span).^2);
    quiver(T,VC,s.*X_world,s.*Y_world,'r','ShowArrowhead','off','AutoScale','off')
    axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax])

    % force the axis to be square
    axis('square');

function y=sqw(t,T,d)
    r=mod(t,T);
    y=(r<d*T/100);
```

[image]

---

One thing to note here is that we used `axis('square')`. This was necessary to ensure an equal scaling relationship between *plot coordinates* and *screen/pixel coordinates*. Since this may not be desirable (maybe we don't want a square plot!), then **we can fix this by dividing `x_span` by the aspect ratio of the axis (in pixels)**. Unfortunately, we can't get the aspect ratio before the plot is created. In order to implement the generalized solution we basically have two options.

1. Write a function handler to automatically re-plot each time the figure is resized. This is more work but generalized.
2. Play with the figure until it is the desired size, then query the size, then use this information to re-plot for the desired figure size.

I chose to pursue option two. First I plotted **without** `axis('square')`, then played with the window until it was about the same size as the original figure that you posted. Next, I queried the position of the figure and aspect ratio as follows

```
>> get(gcf, 'Position')
ans = 666   223   672   505
>> set(gca, 'Units', 'Pixels');
>> get(gca, 'Position')
ans = 88.3600   56.5500  520.8000  411.5750
```

This tells us that for this figure position the aspect ratio of the axis in pixels is `520.8 / 411.575`. Using this knowledge, we modify the function to plot equal length vectors for this non-square axis as follows.

```
function myquiver
    xmin = 0; xmax = 25;
    ymin = 0; ymax = 0.5;

    R=2.3;
    C=1.2;
    V=@(t) 3*sqw(t,1,10);
    F=@(t,VC) (V(t)-VC)/(R*C);
    [T,VC]=meshgrid(linspace(xmin,xmax,10),linspace(ymin,ymax,10));
    S=(3*sqw(T,1,10)-VC)/(R*C);
    L=sqrt(1+S.^2);

    aspect = 520.8 / 411.575;
    x_span = (xmax - xmin) / aspect;
    y_span = ymax - ymin;
    % Compute the scale factor so that vectors are 10% of y-direction of plot window
    d = 0.1;
    X_world = 1./L;
    Y_world = S./L;
    s = d ./ sqrt((X_world / x_span).^2 + (Y_world / y_span).^2);
    quiver(T,VC,s.*X_world,s.*Y_world,'r','ShowArrowhead','off','AutoScale','off')
    axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax])

    % Make the figure have the desired position/size
    set(gcf, 'Position', [666   223   672   505]);

function y=sqw(t,T,d)
    r=mod(t,T);
    y=(r<d*T/100);
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely fabulous. I think you should add the saw function at the bottom of each example, so that when people copy and paste this code it works.

Comment: I found that if I want to draw 20 arrows each way, I simply change the d=0.1 to d=1/20 and it works.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. That would make it so each arrow is 1/20 of the plot window size.